# Matching of tokens with Antlr4

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I am a an Antlr4 newbie and have problems with a relatively simple grammar. The grammar is given at the bottom at the end. (This is a fragment from [a grammar](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/12/S4/S5) for parsing description of biological sequence variants).

I am trying to parse the string `"p.A3L"` in the following unit test.

```
@Test
public void testProteinSubtitutionWithoutRef() {
    ANTLRInputStream inputStream = new ANTLRInputStream("p.A3L");
    HGVSLexer l = new HGVSLexer(inputStream);
    HGVSParser p = new HGVSParser(new CommonTokenStream(l));
    p.setTrace(true);
    p.addErrorListener(new BaseErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object offendingSymbol, int line,
                int charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("failed to parse at line " + line + " due to " + msg, e);
        }
    });
    p.hgvs();
}
```

The test fails with the message **"line 1:2 mismatched input 'A3L' expecting AA"**. I assume that this is related to lexing, i.e. splitting `"A3L"` into the three tokens `A`, `3`, and `L`, such that the parser can then generate the corresponding syntax subtree containing the three terminals from it.

What is going wrong here and where can I learn how to fix this?

#### The grammar

```
grammar HGVS;

hgvs: protein_var
    ;

// Basix lexemes

AA: AA1
  | AA3
  | 'X';

AA1: 'A'
   | 'R'
   | 'N'
   | 'D'
   | 'C'
   | 'Q'
   | 'E'
   | 'G'
   | 'H'
   | 'I'
   | 'L'
   | 'K'
   | 'M'
   | 'F'
   | 'P'
   | 'S'
   | 'T'
   | 'W'
   | 'Y'
   | 'V';

AA3: 'Ala'
   | 'Arg'
   | 'Asn'
   | 'Asp'
   | 'Cys'
   | 'Gln'
   | 'Glu'
   | 'Gly'
   | 'His'
   | 'Ile'
   | 'Leu'
   | 'Lys'
   | 'Met'
   | 'Phe'
   | 'Pro'
   | 'Ser'
   | 'Thr'
   | 'Trp'
   | 'Tyr'
   | 'Val';

NUMBER: [0-9]+;

NAME: [a-zA-Z0-9_]+;

// Top-level Rule

/** Variant in a protein. */
protein_var: 'p.' AA NUMBER AA
           ;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- Define the rule for `protein_var` ahead of the lexer rules (should work now to, but is not easy to read because the other parser rule is ahead).
- Remove the rule for `NAME`. `A3L` is not (as you probably expected) `AA NUMBER AA` but `NAME` <= ANTLR always prefers the longest matching lexer rule

The resulting grammar should look like:

```
grammar HGVS;

hgvs
    : protein_var
    ;

protein_var
    : 'p.' AA NUMBER AA
    ;

AA: ...;

AA3: ...;

AA1: ...;

NUMBER: [0-9]+;
```

If you need `NAME` for other purposes, you will have to disambiguate it in the lexer (by a prefix that `NAME`s and `AA` do not have in common or by using lexer modes).